# nested if statement not working using while read variable

Tags: bash, csv, if-statement, while-loop, nested

I have a csv file that i am reading with a "while read" statement and i want to run an if statement on one of the fields in the csv.

====================================

csv file

```
client1,admin,password,5.9  
client2,admin,password,5.8
```

====================================

this is my script

---

```
while read clientid user pass version  
do  
    if [ '$version' = "5.9" ];  
    then  
        echo "IS"  
    else  
        echo "NOT"  
    fi  
done < $1
```

The problem is that the if statement does not work.
It does not echo IS when the version is 5.9, it just keeps saying NOT, unless i change it to !=
I have tried using single and double quotes, even without... still doesn't work as expected.

The goal is to run commands until the end of the file.
Is this script correct for doing this?

Obviously the IS and NOT would be replaced by actual command, this is just for testing.

Comment: Variables surrounded by single quotes are not evaluated. Use double quotes.

Comment: Also `read` will not split on commas by default. You need to tell it to do that. Print out the value of `$clientid`, `$user`, `$pass`, and `$version` in your loop to see what you get.

Comment: Look into `$IFS` — the Internal Field Separator. This is used by `read` (and many other programs) to separate text strings.

Comment: i do have the IFS="," in the script.
If i echo $version, it displays 5.9

Comment: @baum: can you provide a working example script with `IFS=,` or `read -d,`? I'm getting really weird output when using this.

Comment: @user3870602: your first problem is related to `'$version' = ...`. Single quotes suppress variable expansion, so even if you had the proper value in the `version` variable, you wouldn't be using it.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu, IFS is the field separator. So `IFS=","` followed by a read works. But not `read -d`, that sets the end-line delimiter. Which in CSV, is still a newline.

Comment: @baum: You're right! I know what IFS is; I was just under the wrong impression that -d changes the field delimiter also... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The sample csv file provided has trailing whitespace on the line, which can be removed from the `version` variable using parameter expansion.

This should work:

```
while IFS=, read -r clientid user pass version; do
    if [ "${version//[[:space:]]/}" = "5.9" ]; then
        echo "IS"
    else
        echo "NOT"
    fi
done < $1
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's another:

```
while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -r line; do
    IFS=, read -r clientid user pass version __ <<< "$line"
    if [[ $version == '5.9' ]]; then
        echo "IS"
    else
        echo "NOT"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

- Quote variables in the open always to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion.
- Prefer `[[ ]]` over `[ ]`. It doesn't do word splitting and pathname expansion.
- `IFS=$' \t\r\n'` trims out leading and trailing spaces.
- `__` is added to store surplus values just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `IFS` value comma and whitespace `IFS=', '`  . You will get the exact result.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=', '
while read clientid user pass version  
do
    if [ "$version" == "5.9" ] ; then
        echo "IS"  
    else
        echo "NOT"  
    fi
done < $1
```